# Running a python script using VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm trying to run a python script using a VBA script. However, I think VBA is having difficulties parsing the file paths of my python exe and python script. Please find below my code:

```
Sub RunPythonScript()
Dim shell As Object
Dim exePath As String, scriptPath As String
Dim waitOnReturm As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1


Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
exePath = """C:\Users\Dhruva Rao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"""
scriptPath = """G:\Shared drives\Project Analysis Team\Model v3\Codebase\single_site\main.py"""
shell.Run "cmd /k" & " " & exePath & " " & scriptPath

End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of the cmd prompt:
[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X7zL.png)

Appreciate any feedback on what's wrong here.

Comment: the space in your paths is causing the error. you may need to escape the characters somehow.

Comment: You already have escaped the quotes around the path, so that *should* work...  Not a direct answer to your problem but you should be able to add the directory to your PATH environmental variable so you can just call `python.exe` instead of `C:\full path here\python.exe` - see https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
exePath = "C:\Users\" & chr(34) & "Dhruva Rao" & chr(34) & "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe""
```

Comment: This helped fix my problem. I'm now facing a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' which I'm guessing is because the requests package is not installed.

Comment: @drao96 Glad to ear that. About requests, if you have a pip, you can use command `pip install requests`

Comment: Hey @WaleronTrot, I seem to be running into another parsing issue. I tried using a similar approach to what you had suggested but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code: 
` "G:\" & Chr(34) & "Shared drives" & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & "Project Analysis Team" & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & "Model v3" & Chr(34) & "\Codebase\single_site\main.py"""`

I get the following error message: 'G:\"Shared drives"Project': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @drao96 i make same file in same directory this row works fine for me. `"G:\" & Chr(34) & "Shared drives" & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & "Project Analysis Team" & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & "Model v3" & Chr(34) & "\Codebase\single_site\main.py"` you need to be careful with quotes. For check, put this row in Debug.Print, and then, copy result in cmd. If it is doesn't work - debug it

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, single quotes like:  "G:\Shared drives\Project Analysis Team\Model v3\Codebase\single_site\main.py" did not give me problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you see is that there is spaces in the paths. I have corrected this in the code below and adjusted, so instead of using the """ I use chr(34), which inserts the quotation (")-character inside the string. (I prefer this approach as it makes it clear where the quotation mark is intended.)

However, once that is fixed you will also experience issues with the cmd-part of your shell. The shell itself is the same as the cmd, so by choosing shell.run() you have essentially already started you cmd-prompt and you therefore need to specify which program to run (python.exe).

```
Sub RunPythonScript()
Dim shell As Object
Dim exePath As String, scriptPath As String
Dim waitOnReturm As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1


    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    exePath = "C:\Users\Dhruva Rao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
    scriptPath = "G:\Shared drives\Project Analysis Team\Model v3\Codebase\single_site\main.py"
    shell.Run Chr(34) & exePath & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & scriptPath & Chr(34)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I was able to solve it by following the instructions in the first comment.